# Can't install Gvim

Tags: 12.04, software-center, synaptic, software-sources, gvim

I've installed Gvim and synaptic package manager on 12.04, Gvim had a warning each time I ran it from terminal. So I removed it and tried to install again but came with the following error from software center:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vim-gnome: Depends: vim-gui-common (= 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2) but 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
       Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2) but 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
       Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2) but 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
```

I disabled repositories from software center and just enabled the "main" and the error is still present, software center crashes sometimes too.

What should I do so?

Comment: I guess the problem is unsuccessful remove of gvim because when I try to install the gvim, it's icon appears on the launcher, but the error comes after that, the other opportunity is incompatibility of synaptic.

Comment: there is a common warning with gvim due to not supporting the global menubar.  There's a way to get rid of it, but it's not something to worry about.

Comment: @MartyFried: I've got these: "(gvim:5122): Gnome-WARNING **: Accessibility: failed to find module 'libgail-gnome' which is needed to make this application accessible

(gvim:5122): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type `<invalid>'". Is it that?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that's a different error message; sorry, I don't remember the exact one I used to get - I use Gnome classic, not Unity, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to also enable the update source.

This look like it try to install a old version of gvim while there is a newer version of some components installed, and a strict version checking.

Comment: what can I do that Ubuntu forgets everything about Gvim?

Comment: It looks to me like it's trying to install the same version, not an old version.  Just look at the versions in the error message - they are the same.

Comment: But not the same release : 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 and 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 , note the .1 in the end, so this was a update. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/vim and http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/vim

Comment: I see - same files, same version, but from an updated repository, I assume.  I thought it was a different problem, probably because I don't pay that much attention to the update process.  I just update what it tells me to, and haven't needed to know the details (fortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "vim-common":

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove vim-common
```

And then install "vim" with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim
```

This will install correct version of "vim-common", and later you can install GVim through the software package manager.